# GCC Dependency generation - library headers

Tags: gcc, dependencies, c-preprocessor

I'm including some files from a library and using the gcc preprocessor to generate the dependencies. Right now, if I don't use the -MG option, it includes the library headers as dependencies of my source files. If I use the -MG option (and exclude searching of the library includes when generating dependencies), then it assumes the library headers are auto-generated and does a clean make every time.

Is there a way to treat library headers the same way as system headers?

Comment: Why is it bad for your makefile to think your source is dependent on the library headers? Isn't it?

Comment: +1 @nmichaels.  The program is dependent on the system headers, too...

Comment: While the program is dependent on the library headers, the library is going to change very rarely (and in those cases, one can just make clean). Thus it would be cleaner and faster if I could avoid including the library headers in the dependencies.